# Where to store retry counter in ADFS custom authentication adapter

Tags: ws-federation, adfs3.0

I'm setting up a custom MFA provider for ADFS 3.0 by implementing `IAuthenticationAdapter` in .NET.
This custom adapter generates a random code that is transmitted to the users's mobile phone.

I want to limit the number of times the user can enter the random code, to help prevent a brute force attack.
I have done this using a retry counter that I store in the context that is passed to `BeginAuthentication()` and `TryEndAuthentication()`.

I have just found out, however, that this context is not a server-side thing, but instead is encrypted and transferred to the client in a hidden html field.

The user can now circumvent the retry limit by simply navigating to the previous page, which has the previous value of the retry count, and resubmit that with a new code.

I believe I need to store the retry-count server-side only, but where?
Can't find anything on this in the documentation.

I would hope that ADFS itself would support a retry-limit somehow.

Comment: Perhaps I'd better remove the retry feature altogether..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a server-side place to store data during the authentication process. I believe there is none.

So I deceided to remove the retry feature, thus removing the neeed for server-side session data. 
My on-time-password authentication module can do without this feature.

Still, this does puzzle me. Surely, a more elaborate authentication module would need some place to track the progress of authentication server-side.